# Generate Material Timeline from JSON Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-typescript

I have this Json object generated by BE:

```
{
  "step1": {
    "approved": true,
    "approvalTime": "10-11-2021",
    "title": "title 1",
    "description": "description 1"
  },
  "step2": {
    "approved": true,
    "approvalTime": "10-11-2021",
    "title": "title 2",
    "description": "description 2"
  },
  "step3": {
    "approved": true,
    "approvalTime": "10-11-2021",
    "title": "title 3",
    "description": "description 3"
  }
}
```

Material Timeline:

```
                     <Timeline align="alternate">
                        <TimelineItem>
                            <TimelineOppositeContent>
                                <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary"> // get color form Json
                                    9:30 am  // get this value from JSON
                                </Typography>
                            </TimelineOppositeContent>
                            <TimelineSeparator>
                                <TimelineDot>
                                    <LibraryBooks />
                                </TimelineDot>
                                <TimelineConnector />
                            </TimelineSeparator>
                            <TimelineContent>
                                <Paper elevation={3} className={classesTimeline.paper}>
                                    <Typography variant="h6" component="h1">
                                        title 1 // get title from JSON
                                    </Typography>
                                    <Typography> // get description from JSON</Typography>
                                </Paper>
                            </TimelineContent>
                        </TimelineItem>

                        <TimelineItem>
                            <TimelineOppositeContent>
                                <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
                                    11:00 am // get this value from JSON
                                </Typography>
                            </TimelineOppositeContent>
                            <TimelineSeparator>
                                <TimelineDot color="primary">
                                    <PeopleAlt />
                                </TimelineDot>
                                <TimelineConnector />
                            </TimelineSeparator>
                            <TimelineContent>
                                <Paper elevation={3} className={classesTimeline.paper}>
                                    <Typography variant="h6" component="h1">
                                        title 2 // get title from JSON
                                    </Typography>
                                    <Typography>description 2 // get value from JSON</Typography>
                                </Paper>
                            </TimelineContent>
                        </TimelineItem>

                        <TimelineItem>
                            <TimelineOppositeContent>
                                <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
                                    10:00 am // get value from JSON
                                </Typography>
                            </TimelineOppositeContent>
                            <TimelineSeparator>
                                <TimelineDot color="primary">
                                    <BusinessCenter />
                                </TimelineDot>
                                <TimelineConnector />
                            </TimelineSeparator>
                            <TimelineContent>
                                <Paper elevation={3} className={classesTimeline.paper}>
                                    <Typography variant="h6" component="h1">
                                        title 3 // get values from JSON
                                    </Typography>
                                    <Typography>description 3 // get value from JSON</Typography>
                                </Paper>
                            </TimelineContent>
                        </TimelineItem>

                    </Timeline>
```

Is it possible to set all values from JSON object and set also `Paper` component color based on JSON value using Typescript? When I have `"approved": true` to set green color for `Paper` background.

Comment: Not sure if im completly off. but is this Material Timeline code inside a .tsx file? 
When you have the structure in a variable (lets say myjson) you can simply reference it inside. 

Eg. something like `${myjson.approved ? 'green' : 'textSecondary'}`

Comment: Hi Peter, I'm seeing a few lines in your Material Timeline that reference values that don't appear in the JSON (e.g. `color`, `9:30 am`). Where should I pull these values from?

Comment: You can ignore them for now.

Comment: I'm not sure what "generated by BE" means.  Back End?  Is the JSON coming from a `.json` file in your project directory, or is it something that you are fetching from an API?  The answers that you've got are good, but we're all missing how you get the JSON to pass as a prop.

Comment: What do you mean by _"answer from a reputable source"_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yea you could and its simpler than you might think. There are two main options in achieving this:

1. propagating props - meaning passing the values you need as props for the component that holds the timeline as one of its children:

```
<ComponentWithTimeline steps={<stepsJsonVariableName>}/>
```

styling part of the timeline component

```
classesTimeline:{
    ...classesTimeline
    greenPaper:
    {
        ...classesTimeline.paper,
        backgroundColor: "green",
    }
}
```

Timeline part of component

```
                     <Timeline align="alternate">
                        <TimelineItem>
                            <TimelineOppositeContent>
                                <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary"> // get color form Json
                                    9:30 am  // get this value from JSON
                                </Typography>
                            </TimelineOppositeContent>
                            <TimelineSeparator>
                                <TimelineDot>
                                    <LibraryBooks />
                                </TimelineDot>
                                <TimelineConnector />
                            </TimelineSeparator>
                            <TimelineContent>
                                <Paper elevation={3} className={(props.steps.step1.approved) ? classesTimeline.greenPaper : classesTimeline.paper}>
                                    <Typography variant="h6" component="h1">
                                        {props.steps.step1.title}
                                    </Typography>
                                    <Typography> {props.steps.step1.description}</Typography>
                                </Paper>
                            </TimelineContent>
                        </TimelineItem>

                        <TimelineItem>
                            <TimelineOppositeContent>
                                <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
                                    11:00 am // get this value from JSON
                                </Typography>
                            </TimelineOppositeContent>
                            <TimelineSeparator>
                                <TimelineDot color="primary">
                                    <PeopleAlt />
                                </TimelineDot>
                                <TimelineConnector />
                            </TimelineSeparator>
                            <TimelineContent>
                                <Paper elevation={3} className={(props.steps.step.approved) ? classesTimeline.greenPaper : classesTimeline.paper}>
                                    <Typography variant="h6" component="h1">
                                        {props.steps.step2.title}
                                    </Typography>
                                    <Typography>{props.steps.step2.description}</Typography>
                                </Paper>
                            </TimelineContent>
                        </TimelineItem>

                        <TimelineItem>
                            <TimelineOppositeContent>
                                <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
                                    10:00 am // get value from JSON
                                </Typography>
                            </TimelineOppositeContent>
                            <TimelineSeparator>
                                <TimelineDot color="primary">
                                    <BusinessCenter />
                                </TimelineDot>
                                <TimelineConnector />
                            </TimelineSeparator>
                            <TimelineContent>
                                <Paper elevation={3} className={(props.steps.step3.approved) ? classesTimeline.greenPaper : classesTimeline.paper}>
                                    <Typography variant="h6" component="h1">
                                        {props.steps}
                                    </Typography>
                                    <Typography>{props.steps.step3.description}
</Typography>
                                </Paper>
                            </TimelineContent>
                        </TimelineItem>

                    </Timeline>
```

2. using react context to make the value of the json object available to all child objects ([docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html))

basic example:

```
// Context lets us pass a value deep into the component tree
// without explicitly threading it through every component.
// Create a context for the current theme (with "light" as the default).
const ThemeContext = React.createContext('light');

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // Use a Provider to pass the current theme to the tree below.
    // Any component can read it, no matter how deep it is.
    // In this example, we're passing "dark" as the current value.
    return (
      <ThemeContext.Provider value="dark">
        <Toolbar />
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

// A component in the middle doesn't have to
// pass the theme down explicitly anymore.
function Toolbar() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ThemedButton />
    </div>
  );
}

class ThemedButton extends React.Component {
  // Assign a contextType to read the current theme context.
  // React will find the closest theme Provider above and use its value.
  // In this example, the current theme is "dark".
  static contextType = ThemeContext;
  render() {
    return <Button theme={this.context} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: @PeterPenzov have this answer helped you?

Answer (score 2):

You could conditionally inject a className based on the `approved` field,
here's an example of what the extracted component could look like:

```
const YourCustomComp = (x: {approved: boolean; approvalTime: string; title: string; description: string}) => (
  <>
     ....
     <Paper elevation={3} className={`${classesTimeline.paper} ${x.approved ? 'greenSelector' : ''} `>
        <Typography variant="h6" component="h1">
           {x.title}
        </Typography>
        <Typography> {x.description} </Typography>
     </Paper>
     ....
  </>
)
```

There is also a utility called [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx) that was created for cases like this, I suggest you take a look at it.